# ROS 1 on Ubuntu server 18.04

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ubuntu, ubuntu-bionic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using a Macbook Pro with an M1 chip and I want to install Ubuntu 18.04 on it.

As the M1 chip is arm based, I only can install Ubuntu 18.04 server, not the desktop version.

Can I install ROS 1 on Ubuntu 18.04 on the server edition without any problems?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/379092/ros-1-on-ubuntu-server-18.04./) by [emad55](https://answers.ros.org/users/75191/emad55/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-05-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 server on RPI4 with ros 1 noetic without any problem.

---

Originally posted by [AmirSaman](https://answers.ros.org/users/64433/amirsaman/) with karma: 130 on 2021-05-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running ROS1 on a Raspberry Pi 2 (ARM chip) with Ubuntu 18.04 and it has worked out quite well. If you're able to install Ubuntu on the M1 laptop, I don't think getting ROS1 would be a problem on top of that.

---

Originally posted by [Wes G](https://answers.ros.org/users/8681/wes-g/) with karma: 33 on 2021-05-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2